# If condition in Scrapy

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape a tag in a given url and check if the url link in the tag matches the url of the website. I want to export the results to csv, with a column which indicates if there's a match.

I have the following code, but not sure how to add the matching condition:

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
import csv
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class urlsitem(scrapy.Item):
    status=scrapy.Field()
    url=scrapy.Field()
    canonical=scrapy.Field()


class URLSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301]
    REDIRECT_ENABLED=False
    name = "urls"
    data = ['https://www.wayfair.com/bed-bath/sb0/bedding-c481592.html']
    start_urls =  list(data.iloc[0:,0])


def parse(self, response):

    item=urlsitem()
    item['status']=response.status
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['canonical']=response.xpath("//link[@rel='canonical' and @href]/@href").extract()
    yield item
```

Comment: My bad, please see the edited question. @Carcigenicate

Comment: I added the following in pipeline.py:                                                                           def process_item(self, item, spider):
       item['is_matched'] = 1 if item['canonical']==item['url'] else 0                                                                                    But, it is just giving 0 everytime

Comment: Please, fix the indentation of your code example.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the "**if the url link in the tag matches the url of the website**" part. If you are trying to make a column in the .csv file which indicates the found url is same with the response.url, you can do something like this;

- Create another binary field called `is_match`

`is_match = scrapy.Field()`

- Set it to 1 if the url and the canonical are same, otherwise 0

  `item['is_match'] = 1 if item['canonical'] == response.url else 0`

You can achieve the same behavior with if-else blocks, but this is more elegant. This is called the ternary operator. You can see [this](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) page for further details.

If you want to scrape only the matching urls, then you can put an if block in the `parse` method.

```
if response.url == response.xpath("//link[@rel='canonical' and @href]/@href").extract():
    item = urlsitem()
    item['status'] = response.status
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['canonical'] = response.xpath("//link[@rel='canonical' and@href]/@href").extract()
    yield item
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is giving me a blank excel sheet. I basically want to see if the item['canonical'] and item['url'] are same.

Comment: I tried this, but I am still getting all 0 although the canonical and URL exactly match

Comment: @IshanTyagi That's probably because you are assigning the `is_match` key before scraping the  `canonical`. Put `is_match` assignment after `canonical`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
import csv
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class urlsitem(scrapy.Item):
    status=scrapy.Field()
    url=scrapy.Field()
    canonical=scrapy.Field()
    is_matched=scrapy.Field()


class URLSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301]
    REDIRECT_ENABLED=False
    name = "urls"
    data = ['https://www.wayfair.com/bed-bath/sb0/bedding-c481592.html']
    start_urls =  list(data.iloc[0:,0])


def parse(self, response):
    your_tag = 'XXX'
    item=urlsitem()
    item['status']=response.status
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['canonical']=response.xpath("//link[@rel='canonical' and @href]/@href").extract()
    item['is_matched'] = True if your_tag in response.url else False
    yield item
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is giving me a blank excel sheet. I basically want to see if the item['canonical'] and item['url'] are same.

Comment: Then try,

`item['is_matched'] = 'true' if item['url'] == item['canonical'] else 'false'`